# Piecewise linear function given three points and two crossover boundaries

Tags: r, linear-algebra

Suppose you have three points; (3500, 700), (52500, 5075), and (527500, 36800).  As well as two x boundaries 25000 and 200000.  The question is then to construct three lines (each of which goes through one of the points) in such a way that the lines achieve the same value at each boundary point.  The catch is that the second line must have a lesser slope than the first line and the third line must have a lesser slope than the second line.

I do not believe a solution exists but I would like to know how to set up the problem in order to check for solutions in r.  Ideally, I would like to then relax the constraint that the functions be equal at the boundaries to something where they are within 10% of one another or something like that.

Edit 1:

Essentially what I want is a line that goes through (3500, 700) and has a value (25000, y_1), a line that goes through (52500, 5075) and has values (25000, y_1) and (200000, y_2), and a third line that goes through (527500, 36800) and has a value(200000, y_2).

Edit 2:

Here is an updated graphic.  The dashed lines represent an incorrect solution because the slope of the last segment is larger than the slope of the middle segment (which is 0).  What I am essentially looking for is the y = mx + b format of each of the three segments if they were infinitely extending lines.

[image]

Comment: Three lines that have the same points `(25000, y_1)` and `(200000, y_2)` are the same line. This is by definition.

Comment: I added an edit to clarify

Comment: What is the meaning of "boundary point". At the moment the graphic has two lines. Are you asking if 3 new lines through three points  can have common intersections with both of those lines?

Comment: The vertical lines represent the boundaries.  These lines separate the plane into three parts, each of which has one fixed point.  I would like one line in each of the parts the "connects" with the neighboring line at the boundary point.

Comment: So either of the intersections of those segments with the boundary _lines_ determines the entire system. Just raise up the intersection of the middle segment on the right side until you have either achieved the slope conditions or failed. You should show _your_ coding attempts. This is not a code-writing service. It is intended to support _coders_.

Comment: My main question concerns how to set up the linear system to solve for the solution(s).  I realize now that I should post this question in math.stackexchange first and then come here for coding help.